# Jwplayer displaying captions incorrectly

Tags: jwplayer, captions

I am attempting to use DFXP captions in JWplayer 6

In Flash mode the all of the captions appear as soon as the video starts playing
this happens in all browsers.

In html5 mode they are not working at all.

I have managed to get SRT and VTT files working with the exact same code in all browsers and in both html5 and flash modes.

The Flash version can be seen here
http://www.streaming.co.uk/sam/JWplayer_prototype/Captions_Flash_DFXP.htm

The HTML5 version can be seen here
http://www.streaming.co.uk/sam/JWplayer_prototype/Captions_html5_DFXP.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem - it was an issue with the dfxp file